# Address elements using json path in Jackson and Gson

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson, jsonpath

I want to address elements in a json object using their json path.
Json-path java library provide such facility
[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24412511/basic-use-of-jsonpath-in-java)].

```
 String jsonString = "{\"delivery_codes\": [{\"postal_code\": {\"district\": \"Ghaziabad\", \"pin\": 201001, \"pre_paid\": \"Y\", \"cash\": \"Y\", \"pickup\": \"Y\", \"repl\": \"N\", \"cod\": \"Y\", \"is_oda\": \"N\", \"sort_code\": \"GB\", \"state_code\": \"UP\"}}]}";
 String jsonExp = "$.delivery_codes";
 JsonNode pincodes = JsonPath.read(jsonExp, jsonString, JsonNode.class);
 System.out.println("pincodesJson : "+pincodes);
```

Is it possible to do this using [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) or [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) also instead of using [json-path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) ?

Thanks

Comment: JsonPath is a JSON query library, Gson and Jackson are not and you have to traverse the latter JSON representations yourself. What's the real point of the question?

Comment: I am going to do an performance evaluation and a comparison on similar libraries. Could you please provide me some Json query libraries?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I haven't heard any of such libraries other than JsonPath.

Comment: Sachin Gupta has suggested a way to use Jackson `JsonNode.at`. I didn't know that Jackson provides this out of box. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `at` method of `Jackson` `JsonNode`, which uses JSON pointer expression:

Eg:

```
String jsonString = "{\"delivery_codes\": [{\"postal_code\": {\"district\": \"Ghaziabad\", \"pin\": 201001, \"pre_paid\": \"Y\", \"cash\": \"Y\", \"pickup\": \"Y\", \"repl\": \"N\", \"cod\": \"Y\", \"is_oda\": \"N\", \"sort_code\": \"GB\", \"state_code\": \"UP\"}}]}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(jsonString);
int pincode = node.at("/delivery_codes/0/postal_code/pin").asInt();
```