# How to concatenate json elements with JsonPath (JayWay)

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

Having a simple json:

```
{ "Keys": [
  {"Format": "A", "Subtype": "A1"},
  {"Format": "A",  "Subtype": "A2"},
  {"Format": "B",  "Subtype": "A1"}]
}
```

I would like to generate this result (Format + Subtype concatenation) using JsonPath expressions (without Java specific implementation):

```
 AA1
 AA2
 BA1
```

Is it possible to concatenate the string elements using jsonPath?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The following would give `AA1` as a result.

```
$.concat($.Keys[0].Format,$.Keys[0].Subtype)
```

Similarly

```
$.concat($.Keys[1].Format,$.Keys[1].Subtype) -- AA2
$.concat($.Keys[2].Format,$.Keys[2].Subtype) -- BA1
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this post was a while ago but I'm searching for similar problems. Isn't this the solution?

```
  $.Keys[0].Format$.Keys[0].Subtype
  $.Keys[1].Format$.Keys[1].Subtype
  $.Keys[2].Format$.Keys[2].Subtype
```

Answer (score 0):

You can frame JSON path expressions like:

```
$.Keys[0].Format -- A
$.Keys[1].Format -- A
$.Keys[2].Format -- B
```

and refer to [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24412511/basic-use-of-jsonpath-in-java) the below link to eventually parse it using Jayway.

Comment: As I noted in my question, I am searching for a solution without Java specific implementation. External json format cannot be changed neither.